# Symfony form error translate from helper

Tags: php, forms, symfony, translation

I got a FormErrors helper:

```
class FormErrors implements \JsonSerializable
{

    public function __construct(FormInterface $form)
    {
        $this->form = $form;
    }

    public function all()
    {
        return $this->getErrors($this->form);
    }

    private function getErrors(FormInterface $form)
    {
        $result = array();
        $result[$form->getName()] = array();
        foreach ($form->getErrors() as $error) {
            $result[$form->getName()][] = $error->getMessage();
        }


        foreach ($form->all() as $child)
        {
            $errors = $this->getErrors($child);

            if (count($errors[$child->getName()]))
                $result[$form->getName()][$child->getName()] = $errors[$child->getName()];
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return $this->all();
    }

}
```

which is used like this:
`return (new \Bundle\Util\FormErrors($form))->all();`

but this code doesn't return the messages translated. 
The docs clearly say that $error->getMessage() should return a translated message.

I debugged by locale setting everywhere, and it's not set to english, but I still get an English message.

I rather not inject the container into the helper, because I would than need to change the constructor of the helper, and because I use this function in many places in my app, it could break the code.

Comment: Do you have translation files for your locale?

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov yes

Answer (score 0):

Add your errors in "validators.en.yml" or specify the translation domain for your form might help:

```
$resolver->setDefaults(array(
    'translation_domain' => 'errors'
));
```